# A subset that is closed under multiplication but not addition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I can't get my head around subspaces despite having studied on them quite a lot. Here goes:

**The problem statement, all given variables and data**

Give an example of a non-empty subset U of R^2 such that U is closed under scalar multiplication but is not a subspace of R^2.

**Attempt at a solution**

So a set such as [x1, x2] | x1 >= 0 is NOT closed under scalar multiplication but is closed under addition. I get this but I cannot find an answer in reverse.

A wild guess is x1 + x2 + 2 = 0. I could multiply it and 2x1 + 2x2 + 4 = 0 would still hold true. However, if I wish to perform an addition on it, I don't exactly understand what I add to what equation exactly.. it's all so bogged up. Help would be appreciated. :-)

Comment: Take two lines passing through the origin.

Comment: When you are talking about an equation like $x_1+x_2+2 = 0$, you mean the set of pairs $(x_1,x_2)$ that makes the equation true. For example, $(1,-3)$ is a pair satisfying the equation, since $1 + (-3) + 2 = 0$.  But $(2, -6)$ is a scalar multiple of that pair and does *not* satisfy the equation, since $2 + (-6) + 2 \ne 0$.  So the set you suggested is *not* closed under scalar multiplication as you claimed.

Answer (score 3):

Since you only need a subset for this example- we can "cheat" a bit. We shall define our subset $U$ to be the union of $x$ axis, and the $y$ axis, i.e.

$U$= $\{(x,0):x \in \mathbb{R}\} \cup \{(0,y):y \in \mathbb{R}\}$

Comment: I will admit this is my homework, but I'd rather learn how to do it instead of just get a correct answer. I appreciate your help however! :)